# How to make ember work with Django REST gis

Tags: ember-data, django-rest-framework, gis, geojson, django-rest-framework-gis

I am currently trying to setup ember to interact with Django's REST Framework using the ember-django-adapter.

This works flawless. But since I started using djangorestframework-gis, ember is not able to process the responses anymore.

I have not found anyone building geoJSON with ember except for: https://gist.github.com/cspanring/5114078 But that does not seem to be the right approach because I do not want to change the data model?

This is the api-response:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    9.84375,
                    53.665466308594
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "date_created": "2014-10-05T20:08:43.565Z",
                "body": "Hi",
                "author": 1,
                "expired": false,
                "anonymous": false,
                "input_device": 1,
                "image": "",
                "lat": 0.0,
                "lng": 0.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

While ember expects something like:

```
[{"id":1,
"date_created":"2014-10-05T20:08:43.565Z",
"body":"Hi",
"author":1,
"expired":false,
"anonymous":false,
"input_device":1,
"image":"",
"lat":0,
"lng":0
}
]
```

My take on this was to write my own Serializer:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.DjangoRESTSerializer.extend({
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
        console.log(payload);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
        var features = payload["features"];
        var nPayload = [];
        for (var i = features.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var message = features[i];
            var nmessage = {"id": message.id};
            for(var entry in message.properties){
                var props = message.properties;
                if (message.properties.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
                    var obj = {}
                    nmessage[entry]=props[entry];
            }
            }
            nPayload.push(nmessage);
        };
        console.log(nPayload); //prints in the format above
        this._super(store, type, nPayload);
    },
    })
```

But I receive the following error:

```
The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

What am I missing here? Or is this the wrong approach? Has anyone ever tried to get this to work?

An alternative would be to handle this on the serverside and simply output a regular restframework response and set lat and long in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid answer for the question above. I wanted to share my solution anyways,
just in case anyone ever gets into the same situation:

I now do not return a valid geoJSON, but custom lat, lng values. The following is backend code for django-rest-framework:
Model:

```
#models/message.py

class Message(models.Model):
    def lat(self):
        return self.location.coords[1]
    def lng(self):
        return self.location.coords[0]
```

And in the serializer:

```
#message/serializer.py

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lat = serializers.Field(source="lat")
    lng = serializers.Field(source="lng")
```

Ember can easily handle the format.